# Is it advisable to expose a templated class of a Library?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am developing a Library for Matrix Calculations in C++. For this I wanted to use Templates. After doing a bit of Template Meta Programing, I realized that I would end up in exposing my implementations in the Templatise Matrix Class.Is there any way to obfuscate the template class implementation in the header file when you expose that particular template class ? If yes, then how is it done ?

Comment: I found one way of doing it as doing an implementation in an inline file (*.inl) file. But, still you can see all the implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer from the customer perspective.

When I need to use a library, and integrate it in my code, I expect to see the source code.

It is not because I wish to rip it out from the author... It is not because I am a lawless and irrespective hacker...

It is, simply, because:

- code is documentation, and seeing the implementation of a method will help me compensate for the lack of it, or perhaps better understand what it meant (*)
- for debugging, the ability to step down into library's code is invaluable
- for developing, it is just so much easier if I can compile the code myself, in various flavors (with and without instrumentation, aka gcov, with and without debug symbols, etc...)

I don't ask for the code to be free, I am perfectly fine with the code being licensed, and I'll scrupulously follow the license terms, I just ask for the code to be available.

Frankly, if I have the choice between two libraries, and one does not expose its code, I'll lean toward the other, unless the performance/correctness difference is really important.

(*) In C++, Boost has libraries that I consider fundamentally broken in this regard. The code is riddled with compilers work-around, which makes it very difficult to read. Nevertheless, I use them because they're just awesome.

Answer (score 4):

With current standard (and even upcoming C++11), one has to expose all the `template` definitions where those templates are used. There is no standard way to hide it.

Second part, if you choose to **obfuscate** it, then equally its usage will become complex. The best way in my opinion is to **license/copyright** them!

Answer (score 4):

As templating means that the implementation of the class/function is created compile-time (needs to make a new implementation for each new type) I cannot see how you could hide the code. The only way would be to hide your templates in a precompiled library and only expose interfaces to predefined types. That would lose the template functionality though...

Answer (score 1):

I think all template-based C++ libs are deployed as header files (perhaps also using libraries but the publicly usable templates have to be headers).  That's true for STL, boost, etc.  It's simply the way templates work -- the compiler has to see the original template.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other reasons cited, there's another problem: C++ names are "decorated" - for example in order to support method overloads, the types of the parameters for the method are encoded in the name of the method.

There is no standard for this encoding, it varies from compiler to compiler and even from one version of a compiler to another version of the same compiler.

As a result, if you have a library containing C++ functions, you can't ensure that the names of the functions can be read by your clients (unless you can guarantee that your clients are using the same version of the compiler that you are).

For standard libraries, this isn't a problem, since the libraries are shipped with the compiler, but for other libraries, you need to be *very* careful.

Comment: And still all compilers I have seen ship with the source of their standard libraries.

Comment: That's because of the other reasons mentioned above - the templates need to be published and the standard library includes the "standard TEMPLATE library".  Most compilers I've seen ship with a compiled version (.lib on Windows) of the standard C library (if only for convenience).  They provide source because it's often useful to have the source while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really, since a template is not compiled code.  It's literally a "template".  When a template is instantiated in a .cpp file, the template itself needs to be available to the compiler in order to generate the  code for the class method.  Therefore you can't "hide" the template code ... it has to be available to the compiler, or else you are going to be unable to compile any modules that attempt to instantiate the template.

One good way to think of templates is like a blank form you might use, say for income-taxes or something of that nature.  In order to actually make a valid income-tax form, meaning one filled out with your name, SSN, etc., you need a copy of the "blank" original.  So you can't "hide" the form from a person and expect them to fill it out correctly.  The same is true for the compiler.  When you instantiate a template function or class, a copy of the template needs to be made available for the compiler to fill in the template parameters and actually generate the "real" code behind-the-scenes for you that is then compiled in the code module.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a precompiled header, but I must agree that best way to protect your code is to put license/copyright.